# Figuring out which menu item was triggered in Qt

Tags: qt

In a Qt application, I have a bunch of automatically-created QActions (menu items) that I add to a menu in the menu bar. Each opens a different file. I'd like to connect them all to the same slot so as to not write the same code many times. From that slot, though, how do I figure out which of the QActions was triggered?

(Example: In Cocoa I'd do this with the sender parameter in the action selector.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have two options:

- Call [`sender()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qobject.html#sender) in the slot, which will return the action that triggered the signal.
- Use [`QSignalMapper`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qsignalmapper.html).

Comment: Thanks! QObject::sender() looks like it sufficient for the case I asked about, but it's good to know about the more general QSignalMapper option.

Comment: Further, you can use QObject::setProperty() on your QAction to pass additional per-item data into your slot.

Comment: `QAction::setData` is probably better than `QObject::setProperty`.

Comment: @LukášLalinský
> QAction::setData is probably better than QObject::setProperty
Why you think so?

Answer (score 21):

I would connect to the QMenu's "triggered" signal, rather then each QAction. This gives you the QAction that was clicked as the first parameter.

```
void MyObject::menuSelection(QAction* action)
{
  qDebug() << "Triggered: " << action->text();
} 

void MyObject::showMenu(QPoint menuPos)
{
  QMenu menu;
  menu.addAction( "File A" );
  menu.addAction( "File B" );
  menu.addAction( "File C" );
  connect(&menu, SIGNAL(triggered(QAction*)), this, SLOT(menuSelection(QAction*)));
  menu.exec(menuPos);
}
```

Comment: @neuronet `connect(&menu, &QMenu::triggered, this, &MyObject::menuSelection);`

Answer (score 11):

In Qt, you also have access to the sender: `QObject::sender`.

Comment: Exactly - in your slot you can do something like this:

QAction *pAction = qobject_cast<QAction*>(sender());

Answer (score 0):

As mention above, you have access to the emitter handle via `QObject::sender()`, which is a great feature in Qt (especially when dealing with n amounts of runtime, dynamically instanced objects of unknow type - perhaps defined in a settings file somewhere).