# Difference between toggled and trigger in Qt?

Tags: qt, signals

What is the difference between the toggled and triggered signals in [QAction](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaction.html)?  I don't know when to use one over the other or how they relate.

Moreover, in the documentation for the triggered signal, what does "activated" mean? Is it the same as getting focus?

Thank you...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference lies in what type of widget the action is associated with.  For example, the toggled signal applies when you have an action connected to a (binary) checkbox.  It lets you know whenever the checkbox has been changed from 'on' to 'off' or 'off' to 'on.  The triggered signal, however, applies to transient actions without the requirement that there be an 'on' and 'off' state (i.e. clicking on a menu item or clicking a button).  The usage of 'activated' vs. 'triggered' here is not important, you can think of them as synonyms for a signal without this extra state.

Comment: You can take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1577407/1233859) for sample code using triggered(). 

Clicked just means that you press the mouse button on that widget. :)  That is how something becomes "triggered" or "activated".