# how to know that which QMenu's action is triggered

Tags: c++, qt

I have some QAction and added the same QAction in many QMenu widgets.
All action are are connected to same slot. I want to know that by which QMenu actions are triggered.

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: You can try the [sender()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender) function in the slot, but I'm not sure without knowing more about your app.

Comment: sender() returns a pointer to the object that sent the signal. And signal is send by QAction by this how i know that which QMenu action is triggered.

Comment: If the same `QAction` is bound with the same slot - why do you need to know which one has been triggered? If there is a reason either bind disctinct slots or bind the slot with an additional argument for identification. (assuming you use the new Qt5 style signal binding). (@xander As `QAction` is "shareable" I'm not sure whether `sender()` is sufficient for distinguishing.)

Comment: connect(playlist_action, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(LoadPlaylist()));
And now i added the 'playlist_action' in two QMenu. Now when playlist_action is triggered how to distinguise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking twice, I came to the following conclusion:

If the same `QAction` is added to multiple menus then there is hardly any chance to distinguish in the slot which menu item has been triggered.

`QAction` instances may be shared by multiple menus and toolbars. But it is in this case the same instance (which has multiple parents). The idea to use an additional argument for distinguishing doesn't work for the same reason. There is only one instance of `QAction` with one `triggered` signal – no chance for distinction.

The following sample is the closest I found (`testQActionShared.cc`):

```
#include <QtWidgets>

void actionSlot(const char *text)
{
  qDebug() << "Action triggered:" << text;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  // main application
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QToolBar qToolbar;
  qToolbar.addAction(QString::fromUtf8("Action"),
    [](bool) { actionSlot("action1"); });
  qToolbar.addAction(QString::fromUtf8("Action"),
    [](bool) { actionSlot("action2"); });
  qToolbar.addAction(QString::fromUtf8("Action"),
    [](bool) { actionSlot("action3"); });
  qToolbar.show();
  // run application
  return app.exec();
}
```

`testQActionShared.pro`:

```
SOURCES = testQActionShared.cc

QT += widgets
```

Compiled in bash on [**cygwin**](https://www.cygwin.com):

```
$ qmake-qt5 testQActionShared.pro

$ make
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -D_GNU_SOURCE -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/cygwin-g++ -o testQActionShared.o testQActionShared.cc
g++  -o testQActionShared.exe testQActionShared.o   -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 

$ ./testQActionShared 

Version: 5.9.2
```

The application looks like this:

[image: Snapshot of testQActionShared.exe]

I clicked the three actions with mouse and got the following output:

```
Action triggered: action1
Action triggered: action2
Action triggered: action3
```

This is actually not one shared `QAction` – it's three actions with identical label text and separate lambdas.

The lambdas have been used as adapters to get rid of the unused `bool` argument of `QAction::triggered(bool)` and to bind a string instead.

Note:

I used a `QToolBar` instead of a `QMenu` to keep the sample more compact. However, the principle is the same.

Comment: thanku for giving your time.
I find my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575498/figuring-out-which-menu-item-was-triggered-in-qt?rq=1)

Comment: I've no experience with `QSignalMapper` as I find lambdas even more convenient. (It's probably a matter of taste.) If you could provide a self-answer with a (similar small) sample for demonstration I would be happy to have a look at it. (Never too late to learn something new.) ;-)

Comment: Looking closer at the linked Q/A, I realized those code samples doesn't use one shared `QAction` - they use distinct `QAction`s with the same slot (as well as I did.)

Comment: there is two `QMenu` in my program and i connect those with two different `SLOTS`

`connect(menu1, SIGNAL(triggered(QAction*)), this, SLOT(slot1(QAction*)));`
`connect(menu2, SIGNAL(triggered(QAction*)), this, SLOT(slot2(QAction*)));`
in slots i distinguise the `QAction` with help of `QAction::text`
and perform the further operation.
it's useful for me because i have only two `QMenu` s and many `QAction` s.

Comment: Thank for idea, just added catch 'this'
`connect(copyUrlAction, &QAction::triggered, this, [this](bool) { OnCtxMenuAction(7); });`